# Is mapDispatchToProps the same as mapStateToProps but without passing it state?

Tags: react-redux

I just learned about `mapDispatchToProps`, and Im wondering if its basically the same as `mapStateToProps` but without passing any `state` as `props`?

I mean `mapStateToProps` , passes some props mapped from state AND also `dispatch`.

From what I see `mapDispatchToProps`, also passes dispatch, but no state from props.

So i theory we could use `mapStateToProps`, as it also passes dispatch.. right?

Answer (score 0):

mapDispatchToProps used for dispatching the actions that change the state of reducer in redux-store.

To use state from redux-store we can use mapStateToProps and To use actions we use mapDispatchToProps.

To use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps we have to pass it to connect() of react-redux as connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)()

Comment: but i can still use dispatch if I use mapStateToProps

Comment: No.You have to pass mapDispatchToProps as a second argument in connect() from react-redux to use dispatch